# Password for new user

Tags: software-installation

I just downloaded ubuntu and it requests a password;

I entered my registration password and it didn't work.

Is there an initial password ?

Comment: Downloading of Ubuntu doesn't require any authentication. Could you please add a screenshot to your question?

Comment: Are you at your first boot? Did you maybe mistype your password during setup?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I installed ubuntu except for upgrades, but if I remember correctly the initial installation asks you to set a username and password for the administrator. That would be the person doing the install. You can use whatever username and password you like. I think the last time it didn't like the 7 digit password I had used before and it required an Upper case or special character. But at least it did give me a message telling me when my chosen password was unacceptable.

Comment: There are no special requirements for passwords in most Linux Distros.  Ubuntu is one of them.(I should know)